# Oracle query(PROC) not giving desired results

Tags: sql, oracle

While running below query(inside sproc) oracle..

```
SELECT
    index_name,
    index_description,
    ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(index_keys,','),',') as Index_Keys,
    include_cols,
    index_filter,
    data_compression,
    allow_page_locks,
    table_name,
    index_type
 from
  (
  Select t.*,
    row_number() over (partition by INDEX_NAME order by COLUMN_POSITION) as rn
    from
    (
     SELECT
        di.index_name AS "INDEX_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'clustered'
                ELSE 'nonclustered'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' AND
                     substr (
                    di.index_name,
                    1,
                    3
                ) = 'PK_' THEN ', unique, primary key'
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' THEN ', unique'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'NONUNIQUE' THEN ''
                ELSE ''
            END
        ||
        ' located on PRIMARY' AS "INDEX_DESCRIPTION",
        ci.column_name AS "INDEX_KEYS",
        NULL AS "INCLUDE_COLS",
        NULL AS "INDEX_FILTER",
        NULL AS "DATA_COMPRESSION",
        NULL AS "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS",
        di.table_name AS "TABLE_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'CLUSTERED'
                ELSE 'NONCLUSTERED'
            END
        AS "INDEX_TYPE",ci.column_position
                      FROM
        dba_indexes di
        JOIN dba_ind_columns ci
        ON ci.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           ci.index_name    = di.index_name
                      WHERE
       di.table_owner = '****' AND
        di.table_name = '******' AND
        partitioned = 'NO'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        di.index_name AS "INDEX_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'clustered'
                ELSE 'nonclustered'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' AND
                     substr (
                    di.index_name,
                    1,
                    3
                ) = 'PK_' THEN ', unique, primary key'
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' THEN ', unique'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'NONUNIQUE' THEN ''
                ELSE ''
            END
        ||
        ' located on PRIMARY' AS "INDEX_DESCRIPTION",
        ci.column_name AS "INDEX_KEYS",
        NULL AS "INCLUDE_COLS",
        NULL AS "INDEX_FILTER",
        NULL AS "DATA_COMPRESSION",
        NULL AS "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS",
        di.table_name AS "TABLE_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'CLUSTERED'
                ELSE 'NONCLUSTERED'
            END
        AS "INDEX_TYPE",ci.column_position
    FROM
        dba_indexes di
        JOIN dba_ind_partitions dip
        ON dip.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           dip.index_name    = di.index_name
        JOIN dba_ind_columns ci
        ON ci.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           ci.index_name    = di.index_name
    WHERE
        di.table_owner = '*******' AND
       di.table_name = '******' AND
        di.partitioned = 'YES' AND
        dip.composite != 'YES'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        di.index_name AS "INDEX_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'clustered'
                ELSE 'nonclustered'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' AND
                     substr (
                    di.index_name,
                    1,
                    3
                ) = 'PK_' THEN ', unique, primary key'
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' THEN ', unique'
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN di.uniqueness = 'NONUNIQUE' THEN ''
                ELSE ''
            END
        ||
        ' located on PRIMARY' AS "INDEX_DESCRIPTION",
        ci.column_name AS "INDEX_KEYS",
        NULL AS "INCLUDE_COLS",
        NULL AS "INDEX_FILTER",
        NULL AS "DATA_COMPRESSION",
        NULL AS "ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS",
        di.table_name AS "TABLE_NAME",
        CASE
                WHEN di.index_type = 'IOT - TOP' THEN 'CLUSTERED'
                ELSE 'NONCLUSTERED'
            END
        AS "INDEX_TYPE",ci.column_position
    FROM
        dba_indexes di
        JOIN dba_ind_partitions dip
        ON dip.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           dip.index_name    = di.index_name
        JOIN dba_ind_subpartitions dis
        ON dis.index_owner      = di.owner AND
           dis.index_name       = di.index_name AND
           dis.partition_name   = dip.partition_name
        JOIN dba_ind_columns ci
        ON ci.index_owner   = di.owner AND
           ci.index_name    = di.index_name
    WHERE
      di.table_owner = '***' AND
       di.table_name = '*****' AND
        di.partitioned = 'YES' AND
       dip.composite = 'YES' ) t
)
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
connect by index_name  = prior index_name
and rn = prior rn+1
start with rn =1 ;
```

It gives below output..

![enter image description here][1]

The index keys for AI_TESTORACLE_TEMP_27977 and AI_TESTORACLE_TEMP_27978 currently shows column_name for functional indexes i.e SYS_NC00023$ and SYS_NC00024$ from dba_ind_columns whereas what we expect it should be "TestInt, lower(TestShortString)" and "TestSmallInt, UPPER(TestShortString)"....this is column expression and can be derived from dba_col_expressions view..

```
 Name                                                                    Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------- -------- -----------------------------
 INDEX_OWNER                                                             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 INDEX_NAME                                                              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 TABLE_OWNER                                                             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 TABLE_NAME                                                              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 COLUMN_EXPRESSION                                                                LONG
 COLUMN_POSITION                                                         NOT NULL NUMBER

SQL> desc dba_ind_Columns;
 Name                                                                    Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------
 INDEX_OWNER                                                             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 INDEX_NAME                                                              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 TABLE_OWNER                                                             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 TABLE_NAME                                                              NOT NULL VARCHAR2(128)
 COLUMN_NAME                                                                      VARCHAR2(4000)
 COLUMN_POSITION                                                         NOT NULL NUMBER
 COLUMN_LENGTH                                                           NOT NULL NUMBER
 CHAR_LENGTH                                                                      NUMBER
 DESCEND                                                                          VARCHAR2(4)
 COLLATED_COLUMN_ID                                                               NUMBER
```

Just need small change in this query to output column expressions instead of column name as index_keys ONLY for functional indexes(that's bit tricky)..REST NO CHANGE in other columns..looking for help from all of the experts here..

INDEX_TYPE AS FUNCTION-BASED NORMAL OR NORMAL CAN BE FETCHED FROM DBA_INDEXES

```
SQL> select column_Expression from dba_ind_expressions where table_name='TESTORACLE_TEMP' AND TABLE_OWNER='ROLLOUT';

COLUMN_EXPRESSION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LOWER("TESTSHORTSTRING")
UPPER("TESTSHORTSTRING")

SQL> select column_name from dba_ind_columns where table_owner='ROLLOUT' and table_name='TESTORACLE_TEMP';

COLUMN_NAME
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KEYTESTORACLE
TESTTINYINT
TESTSMALLINT
TESTUNIQUEIDENTIFIER
TESTINT
SYS_NC00023$
TESTSMALLINT
SYS_NC00024$
UPDDATE

9 rows selected.
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

adding index_keys column (current output and expected)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsg0z.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeewU.jpg

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make left join with `user_ind_expressions`. Take value from this table from this table if it is not null, otherwise from `user_index_columns`. Then you can make your hierarchical query, or maybe `listagg()` would be better.

One problem. `Column_expression` is of long data_type (at least I see it in such form), so I made simple function to convert it to varchar (you may improve it, please read proper articles, for instance on asktom site).

```
create or replace function 
  get_expr(i_tn in varchar2, i_in in varchar2, i_cp in number) return varchar2 as

  l_data long;
begin
  select column_expression into l_data from user_ind_expressions
    where table_name = i_tn and index_name = i_in and column_position = i_cp;
  return substr(l_data, 1, 4000);
end;
```

This is my test data and query:

```
create table emp(id primary key, fname, lname, dept) as (
  select 707, 'Pete', 'Griffin', 'Sales' from dual);
create index idx_emp1 on emp(lower(dept));
create index idx_emp2 on emp(upper(lname), upper(fname));
```

and query:

```
select index_name,
       ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(index_keys,','),',') as Index_Keys
  from (
    select t.*, row_number() over (partition by index_name order by column_position) as rn
      from (     
        select index_name, column_name, column_position, 
               nvl(get_expr(table_name, index_name, column_position), column_name) as index_keys
          from user_indexes di
          join user_ind_columns ci using (table_name, index_name)
          left join user_ind_expressions using (table_name, index_name, column_position)
          where table_name = 'EMP') t )
  where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  connect by index_name  = prior index_name and rn = prior rn+1
  start with rn = 1
```

and result:

```
INDEX_NAME      INDEX_KEYS
--------------- --------------------------------
IDX_EMP1        LOWER("DEPT")
IDX_EMP2        UPPER("LNAME"),UPPER("FNAME")
SYS_C00148175   ID
```

As You can see ID is taken from `user_ind_columns`, other keys are from `user_ind_expressions`.

Comment: thanks..Can you share my converted complete query(pasted first in the form)? so i can test that out...also is there any way without using function(create)..we can write this complete query?

Comment: Neither `sys_connect_by_path` nor `listagg` will work with `long` data type, so you have to convert this value to varchar somehow. And function is the only way I know. And second, I focused on problematic part to make answer as clear as possible. Your query is long, you are using DBA views and I cannot. Make joins like above, add `owner` to joining conditions, also add `owner` as function parameter.

Comment: It was a good spot that the Seeker's requirement to include COLUMN_EXPRESSION  meant that [any solution had to wrestle with a LONG column](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-E34E8770-4BCE-47A8-B91A-6BF82889E0C0.htm#REFRN20085).

Comment: @PonderStibbons not working for me..  below is the code updated as per your suggestions..it gives Error at Command Line : 56 Column : 86
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"                                          
          https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vSs39NTTdDDwwRvKzgvznj/0

Comment: Expand this condition `using (table_name, index_name, column_position,table_owner)` to `on ri.table = di.table_name and ri.index_name ...`. Use aliases before column names in other places.